# Unable to retrieve properties from Viewbag item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am retrieving Name and Id of country from db and setting it in Viewbag. But when I am accessing it from view its throwing error.

Here is C# code:-

```
var country = from x in db.Territories select new 
                 {
                  x.Name,
                  x.ID
                 };
 ViewBag.countries = country;
```

View Page Code:-

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
{                
   <td><label class="control-label">@item.Name</label></td>    
}
```

Error:--

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your code.

1. You should create `CountryModel` class, and select list of these models in your action, in the case of using anonymus type you couldn't use it in view.
2. I can suggest you don't use `ViewBag` to pass data to view, the best way is using Model.

Model:

```
public class CountryModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;} 
}
```

Action:

```
var countries = (
    from x in db.Territories 
    select new CountryModel
       {
          Name = x.Name,
          Id = x.ID
       }).ToList();

return View(countries);
```

View:

```
@model List<CountryModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{                
   <td><label class="control-label">@item.Name</label></td>    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewBag is not strongly typed, so MVC doesn't know your `item` is a `Country`, and sees it only as an object.

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
{                
   <td><label class="control-label">@(((Country)item).Name)</label></td>    
}
```

Comment: If I m using your code then getting this error:--                   Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1f`2[System.String,System.Int64]' to type 'Assetry.Model.Country'.

Comment: Your code is wrong, you should convert ViewBag.countries to IEnumerable<CountryModel>, instead item.